# EDITED: How to check value of JSON and compare it to the value of radio button so it can be selected

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have this form that upon opening the HTML file it will read the JSON VALUES and display it to the form..and I need to check if the textbox is the same as the two options "Jollibee" and "Mcdo".

If it is the same it will automatically check either of the two options that has the same value as the textbox, at the same time it will disable the textbox, if not it will select "Other" and the value will be the same. I am getting my values from `JSON` by the way.

[image]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gc54oy7/)

here is my code in JSFIDDLE but i cant make it work in js fiddle but using notepad++ it works fine.. feel free to edit this thank you very much....

HTML

```
<div>Name: <input type="text" id="name" value=""> </div></br>
    <div>Age: <select id="age"></select></div></br></br>

    <p>Favorite fastfood</p>
    <input type="radio" name="fastfood" value="Jollibee">Jollibee<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fastfood" value="Mcdo">McDo<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fastfood" value="Other">Other <input type="text" id="otherfastfood" value=""> </div></br></br>

    <p>Favorite ice cream flavor</p>
    <select id="favorite_flavor"></select></br></br></br>

    <p>House(s)</p>
    <div id="theHouses">
        <div>1. <select id="house-1">
                    <option>Quezon City</option>
                    <option>Makati City</option>
                    <option>Manila City</option>
                    <option>Paranaque City</option>
                </select></div></br>
        <div>2. <select id="house-2">
                    <option>Quezon City</option>
                    <option>Makati City</option>
                    <option>Manila City</option>
                    <option>Paranaque City</option>
                </select></div></br>
    </div>
    <button id="hBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>   
    <button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button></br>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#name').val(info['name']);
   $("#age").html(theAge);
   $("#age").val(info['age']);
   $('#otherfastfood').val(info['fastfood']);
   $('input[name="fastfood"][value="Other"]').prop("checked",true);
   $("#favorite_flavor").html(theFlavor);
   $("#favorite_flavor").val(info['flavor']);
   $("#house-1").val(info['houses'][0]);
   $("#house-2").val(info['houses'][1]);

   $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
   {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
     { 
        if(info['fastfood'])
        {
            $('input[id=otherfastfood]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#otherfastfood').val("");
        }
    }
});

$('#hBtn').click(function()
{
    Houses();
});

$("#myBtn").click(function()
{
    var series = {};
    var h = [];
    var counter = $("[id^=house]").length;
    series.name = $('#name').val();
    series.age = [parseInt($('#age').val())];

    if ($('input[value=Jollibee]').is(':checked')) 
        series.fastfood = $('input[value=Jollibee]').val();

    if ($('input[value=Mcdo]').is(':checked')) 
        series.fastfood = $('input[value=Mcdo]').val();

    if ($('input[value=Other]').is(':checked')) 
        series.fastfood = $('#otherfastfood').val();

    series.flavor = $('#favorite_flavor').val();

    for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++) 
    {
        h.push($('#house-' + i).val());
    }
    series.houses = h;
    alert(JSON.stringify(series));
    });
});

var info = JSON.parse('{"name":"Juan dela Cruz", "age":29, "fastfood":"Jollibee", "houses": ["Manila City", "Paranaque City"], "flavor":"mango", "set_flavors":["ube","matcha","chocolate","mocha","mango"]}');
var counter = 3;
var str = '';

function Houses() 
{
  str = '<div>'+counter+'. <select id="house-'+counter+'"><option>Quezon City</option><option>Makati City</option><option>Manila City</option><option>Paranaque City</option></select></div></br>';
  $('#theHouses').append(str);
  counter++;
}

function theAge()
{
  var agesRange = "";

  for(var a = 1; a <= 100; a++)
  {
    agesRange += '<option>'+a+'</option>';
  }

  return agesRange;
 } 

function theFlavor()
{
   var flavors = "";
   var counter = info['set_flavors'].length;

   for(var a = 0; a < counter; a++)
   {
     flavors += '<option>'+info['set_flavors'][a]+'</option>';
   }

   return flavors;
}
```

Comment: POST code in question, THX!

Comment: Give your JSON also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[value=Other]').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('#otherfastfood').prop('disabled',false)
    }
});

$('#otherfastfood').on('change',function(){
    $('input[name=fastfood]').each(function(custom){
       if($(this).val()!='Other' && $(this).val().toLowerCase()==$('#otherfastfood').val().toLowerCase()){
            $(this).prop("checked",true);   
            $('#otherfastfood').val('');
            $('#otherfastfood').prop('disabled',true)
        }
    });
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gc54oy7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSFiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gc54oy7/2/)

Check for text "Jollibee" in textbox.

```
 $(".nameStr").on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Jollibee"){
        $('.Jollibee').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: class of textbox. I have added it. You can do it with id #name also

Comment: still the same output sir

Comment: I think there is error in other code of your. its giving " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined "

Comment: So use  $('#name').val(); insted of $('#name').val(info['name']);

Comment: yup i already tried it should i remove $('#otherfastfood').val(info['fastfood']); because it shows in the textbox "Jollibee"

Comment: can you give me the link? im trying to check it but it has the same code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8gc54oy7/2/ . I have commented the $("#age"), $('#otherfastfood'),$('input[name="fastfood"][value="Other"]') till  $("#house-2") as there were errors.

Comment: i think i forgot to add something when reloading the same page it will read the JSON values and display it automatically.. so my "fastfood": "Jollibee" in my JSON should be read but will not output in the textbox but instead it will check/select the Jollibee radio button